# How to separate out agents at the output block in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Problem : We have invoice of customers arriving on daily basis. Every month on first day these invoices are sorted out based on the value and all top invoices with 80% of total value is separated to go to one process and bottom remaining 20% is handled by RPA. I wanted to mimic this condition by sending all the entered invoice agent in the collection and then sort it based on the invoice value. Identify the index of the invoice which splits the invoice in 80% and 20% bucket. Then filter this collection above &  below a particular invoice value . E.g if we have invoice amount like ( 5,10,12,12,15,20,21,22)
Invoice value 20 might sperate it into 80% above and 20% below. Using this we can create two batches. I created invoice agent with parameter country and value . tried adding the agent when it enters the queue into collection but failed to see any parameters in the collection.
Attaching the model I tried .

[image]

[image]

I tried looping over collection but not getting any output.
`
double x;

x=  sum( collection, p -> p.Value );

System.out.println(x);

`
if anyone has experienced this situation please share your experience or you know how to solve it.

Comment: Your collection works, you probably call the summing code at the wrong point in time. Why not traceln individual items of the collection? Or use the debugger.

Comment: See this article for more info on problems one can have with the select output https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/select-output-misbehaving

Comment: Can you add more information - it appears as if your select output is working correctly. And in your collection you do see 8 agents?

Comment: I was able to solve this . The parameters values were not populating and hence I was unable to sum up the agents Values in collection. Thanks for your support and advise